# Cannot find the Text Effects >Transform option as indicated in Word Help for Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, transform

As per the help in MS Word 2016, I do not have the option of Text Effects >Transform, all I get when I press shape/text format is another window on the right with format options but none for "wrapping" or "curving" text.  I would like to curve text, not make it round, just curve it from left to right, like if it was on a bottle or jar or tin.  Thanks K.

Answer (score 0):

Please click the shape, then go to Drawing Tools Format -> WordArt Styles -> Text Effects, the last option on the bottom is Transform.

[image]